# How to remove empty spaces at a specific position between specific words using regex?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of string and I want to remove one empty space between words:

```
classes_list = ['CLASS 8B CHEM  | MON | 10AM to 10:40AM', '--Rescheduled-- CLASS 8B MATHS  | MON | 11AM to 11:40AM', 'CLASS 8B HIST  | MON | 5PM to 5:40PM']
```

- I want to remove one space after CHEM, MATHS, HIST
- Look carefully there are two spaces after CHEM, MATHS, HIST

After which if I loop through the list it should print this:

```
'CLASS 8B CHEM | MON | 10AM to 10:40AM',
'--Rescheduled-- CLASS 8B MATHS | MON | 11AM to 11:40AM',
'CLASS 8B HIST | MON | 5PM to 5:40PM'
```

I don't know how to *regular expression* out-here if  possible

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: without regex, simple replace can do the work: `[x.replace("  ", " ") for x in classes_list]`

Answer (score 0):

If your just trying to remove double spaces use `replace`

`[i.replace('  ', ' ') for i in classes_list ]`

```
['CLASS 8B CHEM | MON | 10AM to 10:40AM', '--Rescheduled-- CLASS 8B MATHS | MON | 11AM to 11:40AM', 'CLASS 8B HIST | MON | 5PM to 5:40PM']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the regex that matches zero or more white-space after CHEM, MATHS, HIST:

**`(?<=CHEM|HIST)\s*|(?<=MATHS)\s*`**

and use **`re.sub`** to replaces to a white space [ ].

See [Regex-demo](https://regex101.com/r/8oDU36/1).

**Python resource:**

```
import re

classes_list = ['CLASS 8B CHEM  | MON | 10AM to 10:40AM',
                '--Rescheduled-- CLASS 8B MATHS  | MON | 11AM to 11:40AM',
                'CLASS 8B HIST  | MON | 5PM to 5:40PM']

#regex-pattern
rePattern=re.compile("(?<=CHEM|HIST)\s*|(?<=MATHS)\s*")

classes_list=[rePattern.sub(' ',x) for x in classes_list]
print(classes_list)
```

**output:**

`['CLASS 8B CHEM | MON | 10AM to 10:40AM', '--Rescheduled-- CLASS 8B MATHS | MON | 11AM to 11:40AM', 'CLASS 8B HIST | MON | 5PM to 5:40PM']`

Comment: Why would you put MATHS in a separate expression?

Comment: @tripleee In python, a look behind assertion has to be fixed width. Len of `MATHS` is 5, and the others are 4. They are not the same width that why I separated by `|` to work it.